# Python Print Int as String

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm kinda new to the python language and I'm messing around with various small problems to get used to the language.

Its pretty basic; two arrays of ints and a recursion that adds each level together.

When I go to print the values of each index, I get this error:

> print(total[i])
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Not quite sure that this means? I read somewhere you need to convert it to a string, not quite sure how to do that though.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

```
total = 0

list1 = [207665, 340012, 860174, 830189, 39260, 502042, 582541, 595187, 748907, 627490, 871465]
list2 = [719571, 882606, 559276, 201999, 10167, 249982, 820978, 887870, 205461, 993892, 564934]

x = 11

for i in range(x):
    total[i] = list1[i] + list2[i]

for i in range(x):
    print(total[i])
```

Comment: total is an int, what is total[i]?

Comment: `total = list1[i] + list2[i]` this part just makes `total` an int, i think you want to make it a list

Comment: Put ``print (total)`` in the first loop and look what ``total`` is.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. What are you expecting with `print(total[i])`?

Comment: Should total be a list of zeroes? e.g. `total = [0] * len(list1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `total` as a `list` not as an `int variable`. A variable doesn't have any index, but a list supports indexing and storing multiple values. Like:

```
total = [] #updated

list1 = [207665, 340012, 860174, 830189, 39260, 502042, 582541, 595187, 748907, 627490, 871465]
list2 = [719571, 882606, 559276, 201999, 10167, 249982, 820978, 887870, 205461, 993892, 564934]

x = 11

for i in range(x):
    total.append(list1[i] + list2[i]) #updated

for i in range(x):
    print(total[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, still getting used to arrays in Python. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. If this answer helps you then you can accept the answer by pressing on the tick mark.

Comment: Is it not just exactly same as one answered by @Bono?

Comment: Ha ha... I have answered 19 minuted ago and he answered 15 minutes ago! Is his answer not just exactly same as mine?funny, no?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [numpy](https://numpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) for performance and elegance

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array([207665, 340012, 860174, 830189, 39260, 502042, 582541, 595187, 748907, 627490, 871465])
list2 = np.array([719571, 882606, 559276, 201999, 10167, 249982, 820978, 887870, 205461, 993892, 564934])
print(np.add(list1,list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you initialize total as an integer by assigning it the value 0 in the beginning. Afterward, you always assign it a new value in the first for loop but you always overwrite the existing value. The error is then thrown because you try to iterate through total which is not a list but an integer. Correct solution:

```
total = []

list1 = [207665, 340012, 860174, 830189, 39260, 502042, 582541, 595187, 748907, 627490, 871465]
list2 = [719571, 882606, 559276, 201999, 10167, 249982, 820978, 887870, 205461, 993892, 564934]

x = 11

for i in range(x):
    total.append(list1[i] + list2[i])

for i in range(x):
    print(total[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `total` is `int`.So you could not use `total[i]`(only list and tuple can)

And then use `map()` is better,or you can write like this

`[list1[pos] + list2[pos] for pos in range(x)]`.

```
list1 = [207665, 340012, 860174, 830189, 39260, 502042, 582541, 595187, 748907, 627490, 871465]
list2 = [719571, 882606, 559276, 201999, 10167, 249982, 820978, 887870, 205461, 993892, 564934]

total = map(lambda x,y:x+y,list1,list2)
for i in total:
    print(i)
```

Comment: map() and List-Comprehensions have better performance than ordinary for-loop